# Is it possible to use HTML spellcheck with text-transform: uppercase CSS and all upper-case text?

Tags: html, css, spelling

When an HTML text-area needs to capture data entry in all-capitals, typically the CSS `text-transform: uppercase;` is used to achieve this. Unfortunately, it appears the web browser's built-in spellcheck function seems to ignore all uppercase words by default. Is there any way to change this behaviour? I would like the spell-check to work even though the text is shown to the user in capitals.

In addition to this, after the entered data has been saved to a database in uppercase and then is being edited by the user in a different HTML form, I would like spelling errors to be underlined as such by the web browser's spellcheck function even though at this point they are actually uppercase characters and not just transformed by the CSS into uppercase.

```html
<textarea spellcheck="true">Some delibrate spleling errors.</textarea>

<textarea spellcheck="true" style="text-transform: uppercase;">Some delibrate spleling errors.</textarea>

<textarea spellcheck="true" style="text-transform: uppercase;">SOME DELIBRATE SPLELING ERRORS.</textarea>
```

I'm only interested at this point in changes to the web browser's default behaviour in this regard, I'm not looking to use third party libraries and scripts if this can be avoided. Thank you.

Comment: it's a browser setting, you need to enable it - have a google for spell check uppercase chrome.  Is there any reason to force people to type in uppercase?

Comment: @Pete I've seen these search results but the Enhanced Spell Check still does not treat capitals differently to the Basic Spell Check, it just sends the data off to a central Google server for a more thorough algorithm. It doesn't give any options regarding how the spell check behaves that I can see. In addition, really I'm looking for a solution that isn't specific just to a single browser implementation such as Chrome but ideally one that's standards based and will work in the latest versions of any major browser.

Comment: If i turn on the enhanced spell check it does underline the wrong words but in a slightly different colour: https://pasteboard.co/y9n8GZ9sdHNg.png

Comment: @Pete The Extended Spellcheck only works with Internet connectivity not for offline use cases, and there seems to be an unreasonable delay before things get underlined in grey - I've tried putting spaces in words and clicking all over the place and eventually things get underlined but its not responsive. In addition, light grey underlining is difficult for users to spot. The purpose of all uppercase is to simplify data entry for non-savvy users. It would be nice to have options to configure the spellcheck behavior. e.g. spellcheck="uppercase" rather than just spellcheck="true".

Comment: as it's a browser setting, it would entirely depend on how the user has set their browser up anyway, the only thing you could do is use a js plugin to do it client side, but as you've said you don't want to use a plugin so there's not much more you can do